# Where does this Fortran variable come from?

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

Can anyone tell me about the `costh` variable used in the following subroutine? From where is the subroutine obtaining the value of this variable? Is it some error or inbuilt function?

The complete subroutine is given below.

```
SUBROUTINE MOMENT(I,A,AP,MODE,EP,NCASC,ID)
      COMMON/MOM/VY(99996),VZ(99996),VX(99996)
      DIMENSION ERES(99996),FCT(99996)
  COMMON/XQANG/SUM(300,10),MDIR,COSTH
  EQUIVALENCE(ERES(1),VY(1)),(FCT(1),VZ(1))
  IF(ID-2)10,30,40
   C     INITIALIZATION
    10 N=1
  NN=N+NCASC-1
  DO 20 J=N,NN
  VY(J)=EP*MDIR
  VX(J)=0.
20 VZ(J)=EP*(1-MDIR)
  GO TO 60
C
C   CALCULATION OF MOMENT
C
CKM   30 RN4=RANF(0.)
30 RN4=RAN(ISEED)         !KM
  PHI=6.28318*RN4
  SOX=2.*AP*EP/(A**2*931.5)
C     BUG FIX  A*(AP+A)REPLACED BY A**2 12/15/82
C     IF(SOX.LT.0.)WRITE(*,943)AP,EP,A
  VT=SQRT(SOX)
  SOX=1.-COSTH**2
  IF(SOX.LT.0.)SOX=0.
  SINTH=SQRT(SOX)
  VZSE=VT*COSTH
  VYSE=VT*SINTH*SIN(PHI)
  VXSE=VT*SINTH*COS(PHI)
  VZ(I)=VZ(I)+VZSE
  VY(I)=VY(I)+VYSE
  VX(I)=VX(I)+VXSE
  VZP=VZ(I)-VZSE*(A/AP+1.)
  VYP=VY(I)-VYSE*(A/AP+1.)
  VXP=VX(I)-VXSE*(A/AP+1.)
  VPP2=VZP*VZP+VYP*VYP+VXP*VXP
  EPART=AP*VPP2*469.
  SOX=0.
  IF(VPP2.GT.0.0)SOX=VZP/SQRT(VPP2)
  C      DO NOT USE QUICK FUNCTIONS HERE
  ANG=ACOS(SOX)*180./3.1415927
  CALL OUTEM(2,MODE,EPART,ANG)
  GO TO 60
  C
  C   END CALCULATION
  C
  40 VFTS=VX(I)**2+VY(I)**2+VZ(I)**2
  ERES(I)=0.5*A*VFTS*931.5
  IF(VFTS.NE.0.)GO TO 50
  FCT(I)=0.0
  GO TO 60
  50 FCT(I)=ACOS(VZ(I)/SQRT(VFTS))*180./3.1415927
  60 RETURN
  END
```

Comment: Add `implicit none` as your second line to see. Note also that `costh` appears in the `common` statement of line four.

Comment: I do not want any modifications in the program. As I have a program of arond 100 pages and this is only part of it.
I just need to know about the variable costh.

Comment: What I mean Is: search questions here to try to understand common.  Try [tag:fortran-common-block].

Comment: I did that, it just give list of variables to be used. We have value for MDIR already. But COSTH is appearing here only in the whole program (in this subroutine block)

Comment: Not wanting modifications to code is your prerogative, however many have had success with using "testing harnesses" to allow for verifying that a subroutine or function is working. And then to update the code to better practices such as modules. This is most easily done when one has some standard inputs and outputs to determine that it is working as intended. Adding in IMPLICIT NONE is usually a worthwhile first modification that one often undertakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
COMMON/XQANG/SUM(300,10),MDIR,COSTH
```

informs the subroutine about a *common block* called `XQANG` which has an element called `COSTH`.  In the absence of other information, and in a code of that vintage, this is most likely to be a `real` variable.

Common blocks are an early-Fortran mechanism for sharing variables across program units, such as between a main program and a subroutine.  In  straightforward use the same common block declaration will be found in multiple locations, with the same list of variables. Each declaration refers to the same variables.

There is a twist though, and one to watch out for carefully.  The common block is actually a shared block of memory, and there is no requirement that each instance of the declaration identify the same variables.  One common use of common blocks was to declare, say, an array of 100 reals in one location, but to declare two arrays each of 50 reals elsewhere -- same memory, different variables.

Even better, they could also be used to change the types of variables (sort of).  One usage of a common block might contain a real variable occupying 4 bytes, while another usage of the same block might contain a 4-byte integer variable at the same location - same bits, different interpretations.

These twists are among the reasons for common blocks being widely deprecated. Another reason for their deprecation is that they obscure the sharing of variables, these days most of us prefer to explicitly pass arguments into and out of subroutines through their argument lists.

I'd guess very few Fortran programmers under 50 are still writing new code using them.  But Fortran programmers from 8 - 80 are still working on codes containing them.

Comment: COSTH is used only in this subroutine.
While this common block is used elsewhere also but instead the last variable is CT. Should I look for it's values?

Comment: Yes, I repeat yes, to get over SO's threshold for minimum comment length.

Comment: Assuming the variable `MDIR` has the same size in memory as `COSTH` and each element of `SUM`, the common block `XQANG` is a blob of memory 3002 elements long, the last of which is accessible in this routine by the name `COSTH`. If there are other routines which contain the `XQANG` common block, the last element in them refers to the same memory element as `COSTH`. For example, in `COMMON /XQANG/ A, Z(100,30), B`, `COSTH` refers to the same memory element as `B`. This is called *storage allocation* and it's an awful hack left over from the days before dynamic memory allocation in Fortran.